# SceneKit - make SCNNode rotate horizontally but not spin multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift3, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

Ok, having a weird time rotating a SCNNode based off a joystick, just rotate to an angle defined by the joystick. Im mimicking Apple's Fox WWDC demo, so I get the angle of my joystick and transform it as they did to a CGFloat -

I am just trying to rotate my node on the horizontal axis (not in y direction only x) so that it

faces the camera point of view when joystick is DOWN and

faces forward when joystick is UP

I have this working to a degree but not all the way. Don't know why - problem is I need the same SIDE of my node (its a cube) to face say the left if joystick is down - right now this may or MAY NOT happen depending on how many spins the cube has undergone in getting to this back facing (DOWN) angle.

For example if I have a dot on the back face of node, I need that dot to ALWAYS face user/camera if the joystick is pointed down and cube has spun to point to user.

So far I get the angle from joystick (all from Apple) in float2 - look at cameraDirection:

```
func padOverlayVirtualStickInteractionDidStart(_ padNode: PadOverlay) {
        //control char
        if padNode == overlay!.controlOverlay!.leftPad {
            characterDirection = float2(Float(padNode.stickPosition.x), -Float(padNode.stickPosition.y))
        }

        //control world
        if padNode == overlay!.controlOverlay!.rightPad {
            cameraDirection = float2(Float(padNode.stickPosition.x), -Float(padNode.stickPosition.y))
        }
    }

    func padOverlayVirtualStickInteractionDidChange(_ padNode: PadOverlay) {
        //control char
        if padNode == overlay!.controlOverlay!.leftPad {
            characterDirection = float2(Float(padNode.stickPosition.x), -Float(padNode.stickPosition.y))
        }

        //control world
        if padNode == overlay!.controlOverlay!.rightPad {
            cameraDirection = float2( -Float(padNode.stickPosition.x), Float(padNode.stickPosition.y))
        }
    }
```

Convert this again:

```
var worldDirection = float2()
public var cameraDirection: vector_float2 {
        get {
            return self.worldDirection
        }
        set {
            var direction = newValue
            let l = simd_length(direction)
            if l > 1.0 {
                direction *= 1 / l
            }
            self.worldDirection = direction
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
func updateWorldRot() //called in update
    {
        if(overallWorldNode != nil)
        {
            let newDir = worldDirection(withPointOfView: sceneRenderer?.pointOfView)
            if !newDir.allZero() {

               worldDirectionAngle = CGFloat(atan2f(newDir.x, newDir.z))
            }
                //print("NODE: ", platformsSpawned[currentLevel]?.first?.node.rotation)
                //print("ANGLE: ", worldDirectionAngle)
        }
    }
 func worldDirection(withPointOfView pointOfView: SCNNode?) -> float3 {
        let controllerDir = self.cameraDirection
        if controllerDir.allZero() {
            return float3.zero
        }

        var directionWorld = float3.zero
        if let pov = pointOfView {
            let p1 = pov.presentation.simdConvertPosition(float3(controllerDir.x, 0.0, controllerDir.y), to: nil)
            let p0 = pov.presentation.simdConvertPosition(float3.zero, to: nil)
            directionWorld = p1 - p0
            directionWorld.y = 0
            if simd_any(directionWorld != float3.zero) {
                let minControllerSpeedFactor = Float(0.2)
                let maxControllerSpeedFactor = Float(1.0)
                let speed = simd_length(controllerDir) * (maxControllerSpeedFactor - minControllerSpeedFactor) + minControllerSpeedFactor
                directionWorld = speed * simd_normalize(directionWorld)
            }
        }
        return directionWorld
    }
```

Then I apply to the node:

```
 public var worldDirectionAngle: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            overallWorldNode.runAction(
                SCNAction.rotateTo(x: 0.0, y: worldDirectionAngle, z: 0.0, duration: 0.2, usesShortestUnitArc:true))
        }
    }
```

What can I do to stop multiple rotations?